# Can new keywords be added to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, keyword, specifications, ecma262

From what I understand, the answer is "yes." But assuming that's true, how is it possible?

Wouldn't it violate the WHATWG's [design principle #2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#support-existing-content)?  I mean, let's assume that the keyword `foo` was added as a keyword in ECMA-262. wouldn't code that was written and deployed years ago, and that potentially uses `foo` as an identifier totally break?

Maybe I'm just wrong and the answer is no.  That said, I really have no choice but to ask on here, since googling for "new javascript keyword" or any variation on the query unsurprisingly yields a ton of crap about, well, the `new` javascript keyword.

Comment: You mean, in new editions of the ECMAScript standard? Performed by the standards body?

Comment: Not all keywords can be syntactically used as identifiers; moreover, there are certain reserved keywords already.

Comment: Also, define "keyword". Do you mean a reserved word? I'm mentioning this because (according to the standard), a reserved word is a super-set of a keyword, which also includes other types of reserved words, like future reserved words.

Comment: I think for ECMAScript, you should [refer to ECMAScript Language Specification itself](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1.2)

Comment: `From what I understand, the answer is "yes."` - What is it that makes you think you can create new keywords?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer -- I meant in future versions of the specification, exactly like @Šime Vidas said.

Comment: @adlwalrus: An example may be the `module` keyword. If you run Node.js as `node --harmony`, then `module A {}` parses fine, and at the same time `module` as an identifier refers to the node variable.

Comment: @pimvdb that *is* interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you as a developer can not define new keywords that are not part of the specification.

Yes, the standards board could add new keywords or reserved words, but generally they avoid doing so for the breakage reason you state.

Comment: Awesome, all I was looking to find out. Thanks!